# Where can I find the Goth Cap?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

So.. I'm stuck in here , I talked to the goth kids and he said I have to buy cigarretes, coffee , goth clothes, goth gloves and the goth cap, I did most of that, but the homeless doesn't sell the goth cap, I already checked my inventory but I don't have it yet.
[image]
[image]

Where can I find the Goth Cap?

Comment: The Goth Cap is sold by the same hobo who sells the other items. If he doesn't have it, you don't have it, and it's not available on the buyback page, this is a bug or you're mistaken.

Comment: No buyback page :(

Comment: If it's definitely not in your inventory, the hobo's store, or the buyback page, try reloading the game.

Comment: Already try , Nothing...

Comment: It's a long shot but can you post a screenshot of your inventory and one of the hobo's store?

Comment: Done ,I already bought everything of equippment in the hobo store

Comment: Did you accidentally sell it to another store? try looking at other shops in their buyback pages....